# Como faço pra trocar a 3 e a 5 ocorrencia de uma palavra em uma string

Tags: python-3.x

Alguem pode me ajudar nisso, eu preciso trocar a 3 e a 5 ocorrencia de uma palavra em um texto, n posso mudar as demais ocorrencias.

```
Texto=input("Digite o Texto: ") #recebendo o texto do usuario

Palavra=input("Digite a Palavra: ")#Recebendo a palavra do usuario

cont=Texto.count(Palavra) #atribuindo a cont...

print(cont) #Imprimindo a quantidade de ocorrencias da palavra


Text_Aux=Texto.replace(Palavra, "TROCADO",3)#trocando as 3 primeiras ocorrencias

Texto=Text_Aux# atribuindo a string auxiliar a original
```

Comment: Uma pergunta quer trocar a palavra quando esta se repetir na string pela terceira/quinta vez, no mesmo/só no sitio onde foi encontrada a terceira ou quinta ocorrência certo?

Comment: apenas na 3 e na 5 vez, e nenhuma outra mais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
my_str = 'Isto é o meu texto , sim é o meu querido texto , gosto muito deste texto ... Melhor texto do mundo, sim é um texto '
words = my_str.split()
words_count = {}
for k, val in enumerate(words):
    words_count[val] = words_count.get(val, 0) + 1 # caso val não haja como chave do dict vamos colocar o valor 0 e somar 1
    if words_count[val] == 3:
        words[k] = 'YOOOOOO'
    elif words_count[val] == 5:
        words[k] = 'HEYYYYYYY'
new_str = ' '.join(words)
print(new_str) # Isto é o meu texto , sim é o meu querido texto , gosto muito deste YOOOOOO ... Melhor texto do mundo, sim YOOOOOO um HEYYYYYYY
```

Neste caso a palavra "é" é repetida 3 vezes e trocada na ultima (terceira ocorrência) e a palavra "texto" é repetida 5 vezes, trocada na terceira e quinta ocorrência

Comment: problema resolvido, vou tentar implementá-lo aqui no meu código, obrigado :D

Comment: De nada @AdrianoBrito, ainda bem

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta já foi muito bem [**respondida pelo Miguel**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147113/6454), segue abaixo uma alternativa que manipula os índices da *string*:

```
def trocar (texto, substituir, substituto, ocorrencias):
    indice = texto.find(substituir)
    cont = texto.count(substituir)
    ret = texto
    n = 1

    while indice >= 0 and n <= cont:
        if n in ocorrencias:
            ret = ret[:indice] + substituto + ret[len(substituir) + indice:]        
        indice = ret.find(substituir, indice + len(substituto))
        n += 1

    return cont, ret
```

A função retorna uma *tupla* com o número de ocorrências da palavra na *string*, e o texto modificado.

Exemplo de uso:

```
texto = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#         ↑  ↑  ↑  ↑  ↑
#         1  2  3  4  5

print(trocar(texto, "xxx", "AAA", [1, 2])) # (5, 'AAAAAAxxxxxxxxx')
print(trocar(texto, "xxx", "BBB", [2, 3])) # (5, 'xxxBBBBBBxxxxxx')
print(trocar(texto, "xxx", "CCC", [3, 4])) # (5, 'xxxxxxCCCCCCxxx')
print(trocar(texto, "xxx", "DDD", [4, 5])) # (5, 'xxxxxxxxxDDDDDD')
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/YKHVVh)

No teu caso, você pode chamá-la assim:

```
texto = input("Digite o texto: ")
palavra = input("Digite a palavra: ")

cont, trocado = trocar(texto, palavra, "YYY", [3, 5])
print ("{} aparece {} em {}\n".format(palavra, cont, texto))

print (texto)
print (trocado)

# Exemplo de saída
#   Digite o texto: foo foo foo foo bar foo
#   Digite a palavra: foo
#   foo aparece 5 em foo foo foo foo bar foo

#   foo foo foo foo bar foo
#   foo foo YYY foo bar YYY
```

Comment: Eu consegui implementar um código bem mais simples, com umas 5ou 6 linhas apenas, e usando if e for, amanhã pela manhã coloco aqui.